# JQuery select multiple classes

Tags: jquery

I am trying to select elements that have certain classes.

following will only select classA:

```
 $('.holder').children('div[class*=classA]');
```

Divs can either have classA or classB and other classes as well together!

so it can be like this:

```
<div class="holder">
    <div class="classA"/>
    <div class="classA otherClass"/>
    <div class="classB"/>
    <div class="classB thirdClass"/>
    <div class="whatever"/>
</div>
```

How do I select all elements with classA and classB?

Comment: Self closing elements? Blasphemy!

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Have a look at this http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/

Comment: Also note a wildcard search like you demonstrate will expand to all matches, e.g., `div[class*=classA]` will match `.classA` and `classAB`. Probably not what you want.

Comment: Simply calling children() without a selector argument will return all 4 elements.

Comment: @ mathewbergt  That is true, but there can be other elements as well. I will edit the question now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use `,` (comma) to separate your selectors:

```
$('#holder').children('.classA, .classB, .thirdClass, .otherClass')
```

Demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/mEAFh/1

Comment: Make sure you are NOT using self closing div elements, otherwise this answer does not work.

Comment: @mathewbergt - To be sure, the answer will continue to work, the *markup* will not.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the "find" function, on the $('#holder') object as

```
var myDivs = $('#holder').find('.classA, .classB')
```

Loop the object **myDivs** to get each individual div with the requested class.